# How to setup AutoKey for text auto-completion

Tags: text-editor, text, auto-completion, productivity, autokey

How do I setup [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) to get the following result?

1. I type a word like **ubu** in a text editor
2. A window opens with the suggestion **ubuntu**
3. I can select **ubuntu** through TAB-key
4. **ubu** gets replaced with **ubuntu**

Comment: Have you looked at [texpander](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander)? It requires a couple of small packages to be installed if you don't already have them. Assuming you have created a list of often-used phrases, when you invoke texpander by a shortcut combo you set up, a zenity window opens and you can select the phrase you want to install. In that sense, it's different than Autokey which, I assume will only provide hits related to `ubu` (in your example).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Does it recommend words or filter words in that zenity window based on what I typed?

Comment: You need to create a folder, `~/.texpander`, and put in each phrase/string you may need to insert into a document into separate text files. Then, when you need to insert a particular phrase/string, press the shortcut to run `texpander`, I use Ctrl+tilde, the zenity window appears: if you've been cunning enough to name your text files in `~/.texpander`, typing one or two letters is enough to select the phrase/string you want. Pressing enter inserts the chosen phrase/string. I like it because it runs only when needed unlink Autokey.

Comment: The last sentence should read: I like it because it runs only when needed unlike Autokey.

Comment: I tried multiple times to get Texpander to work. It is really frustrating. The zenity window does not show up

Comment: I took a chance and posted. Note the use of `xsel` because that's what the script uses instead of `xclip`.

Comment: If [you're on 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075244/does-power-pause-work-the-same-as-hibernate), it's possible you can't install the additional packages needed for Texpander to work!

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this may not work in a Wayland session!**

[Texpander](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander):

> Texpander is a simple text expander for Linux. It is sort of like Autokey, except it works off of text files that you put in your `~/.texpander` directory. Texpander is a bash script that uses `xclip`, `xdotool`, and `zenity` to let you type an abbreviation for something and it expands to whatever you have in the matching text file.

[Download the `.zip` file](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander/archive/master.zip) and extract the contents.

Copy `texpander.sh` over to `~/bin`. Make it executable.

Use your distro's method to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>, for example, to `texpander.sh`. (Note that `~/bin` should be in your `$PATH`.)

Install `xsel`, **not** `xclip`, and `xdotool` using `sudo apt install`.

Create a folder `~/.texpander`.

In that folder, create the following three files: `au.txt`, `off-topic.txt` and `os.txt` with the following contents:

**au.txt**

> Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

**off-topic.txt**

> Questions about distros other than Ubuntu or other official flavors are off-topic here.

**os.txt**

> OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Open a text editor and press the assigned shortcut to launch `texpander.sh`. You'll get a Zenity window like this:

[image: Texpander choices]

If you have a longer list, there'll be a handy scrollbar or just type the first letter of a listed item to jump down the list to that item.

Select the one you want and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click `OK`.

[image: A longer list with scrollbars]

**Troubleshooting:** If things don't work, try increasing the `sleep` values in lines 45 and 61 of `texpander.sh`. `xdotool` on older machines may benefit.

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much for the tutorial. The only thing I'm missing at this point is that the window pops up as soon as a phrase gets detected. A workfow like this: I type -->Stack -->Window pops out -->Highlights Stackexchange -->I just need to press enter -->Stack gets replaced with Stackexchange. Could that be added to TexPander?

Comment: I would think not. That would require Texpander to be running constantly to monitor the keys pressed by the user. That's partly why AutoKey is constantly using resources. Texpander runs only when invoked by the shortcut key you use to call it.